# How to display an svg string (not a file) in emacs

Tags: shell-mode, svg

I have a python program that uses graphviz to generate an svg image that it prints out.  When I run that in a shell buffer I see a textual representation of the svg image.  I'd like to see instead the generated image.  How do I take that text in emacs and get something that shows me the image?

Comment: Pipe the output of the python program into the standard input of an image display program that can read from stdin (e.g. `display` which is part of ImageMagick, can read stdin: `cat foo.svg | display -`)

Comment: Ok, thanks that is helpful.   Now I will go look for imageMagick and how to install it....

Comment: Check whatever image display program  you have available first: `display` is just one example that should work.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that graphviz writes that image to a file and if I simply open a buffer to that file, emacs displays it (in that buffer).  It's not quite as magic as what Jupyter notebooks do, as I have to manually open the file (or fix my comint-send-command to do that for me).  If this comment was an answer, I would have accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where and how you are running Emacs, but I think graphical Emacs can show the svg image itself also in most cases. Then the following answer is an alternative to the answer by @NickD in the comments.

I am not sure if you need to run the command in a shell buffer per se, but otherwise you could also use the following command (via `M-x` or create a keybinding):

```lisp
(defun display-output-as-image (command)
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-shell-command (if shell-command-prompt-show-cwd
                            (format-message "Shell command in `%s': "
                                            (abbreviate-file-name
                                             default-directory))
                          "Shell command: ")
                        nil nil
            (let ((filename
                   (cond
                (buffer-file-name)
                ((eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
                 (dired-get-filename nil t)))))
              (and filename (file-relative-name filename))))))
  (shell-command command
   (pop-to-buffer "output.svg"))
   (image-mode))
```

Then, after calling this command, you can simply type in the command and the image will show in an Emacs buffer.